# Windows 7 32-bit SP1 - Aero stops working after logging out, locking, getting UAC Secure Desktop prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, aero

I have a Windows 7 desktop (Core 2 Duo E8400, 4 GB DDR2, AMD Radeon HD 8570 1 GB). Aero works fine and doesn't cause any issues. However, any time I do Control-Alt-Delete, get a UAC prompt (with Secure Desktop enabled), or lock/log out (and then log back in later), Aero quits working and the system reverts to the Basic theme. I can run the Aero troubleshooter, and it will fix it, as well as warn me that DWM was disabled.

I imagine something about going to a separate desktop type (UAC, Ctrl-Alt-Del, Login Window) makes an error or uses too many resources? It would be nice to get DWM to behave properly, as needing to wait for Aero diagnostics every time I do any of these things is annoying. How can I fix this issue?

- Wynter

Comment: Each desktop user should be logged out after use. Log out of all desktops, shut down, start up in only ONE desktop. Does Aero work correctly. Do Ctrl Al Del.  Does UAC pop up? It should not if started as I suggested above.

Comment: There is only one account (save for Guest) on the machine, and Guest is never used. I'm the only one who ever uses the machine as it is a headless remote desktop. I have UAC set in Local Security Policy not to enable the secure desktop (fade the rest of the desktop out) and this fixes the UAC part of the issue.

Comment: Maybe run SFC from an admin command prompt to fix remaining errors.  SFC /SCANNOW.  I have a Windows 7 machine here and it does not do this.

Comment: "How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7" by Shawn Brink https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html